# Apply moving average on the indepdentent variable too if its non-equidistant?

Tags: time-series, smoothing

Given some XY-data where X is the non-equidistant independent variable and Y the dependent variable. Let say the data comes from a physical experiment. I want to smooth this data using a rolling/smoothing average filter. How should I proceed?

What I often do in this case is to apply the same filter on both Y and X, but I'm not sure whether this is statistically correct. I think it's clear that I cannot just apply normal running average on Y alone given the non-uniform spacing of the independent variable. Filtering the independent variable has also the advantage that I can easily use even-sized windows without introducing a lead/lag.

As an alternative I think interpolating the data on a regular grid, but like this I feel that as I change the sampling of my data, I actually generate artificial data-points ("measurements") which get the same weight as the actual measurements, which I find strange.

So, what is the correct way to apply a filter as e.g. running average in this case?

EDIT:

One of my reason is the following: In a physical experiment, every variable is an "experiment", so if smooth one variable, I can (should) also smooth the other variable. Because what is dependent and independent is just a point of view...

here an example, it's obvious that only smoothing Y gives unreasonable results, whereas smoothing X and Y seems to give represent the original data much better.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# position
x = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,7.8,8,9,10.0,11.0])

# velocity
y = np.array([0.9,4.1,9.5,15.8,25.0,60.4,64.7,81.5,70.4,85.4])

N=3 # window size

# convolution with rectangular window (= moving average)
y_rm= np.convolve(y, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='valid')
x_rm= np.convolve(x, np.ones((N,))/N, mode='valid')

plt.plot(x,y,'-o',label="original", lw=2)
plt.plot(x[0+(N-1)/2:(x.size-(N-1)/2)],y_rm,'-o',label="smooth Y")
plt.plot(x_rm,y_rm,'-o',label="smooth X & Y")
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("position (m)")
plt.ylabel("velocity (m/s)")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: I like to use weighted averaging in this case.  All averaging is weighted, but if it isn't explicit the weights are equal.  I wouldn't necessarily use the same filter on the range as I would on the domain.  If you want measures that are close together to not weigh as much then weighing them by the distance to the nearest neighbor can work.  ... perhaps average distance to nearest 3 neighbors.  Why is clustering showing itself in smoothing... fun.

Comment: Can you provide a small example dataset to illustrate what you're asking about? Why would you want a rolling average of anything?

Comment: @gung Why apply running average on "everything"? Why not? Why should I treat X and Y differently? I try to make a sample dataset

Comment: I work as a statistical consultant for a living. I don't recall ever seeing anyone conduct running averages on their data like you're describing. Are you just hoping for extra unnecessary work before you get on with your analysis? Why not always add $\sqrt \pi$ to all your X & Y data? Why not? Why should you treat them differently? Surely there's some reason for wanting to do this.

Comment: @gung I added an example. If you are a statistical consultant, then I would appreciate your answer I'm just a physicist and data scientist for living.